# In a five card hand how many three of a kinds can I generate?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

have been trying to wrap my head around solving this. So far this is what I got. But for some reason I keep getting the wrong answer. According to some research I need the multiply the number of combinations of the last two cards(not the three of a kind) by 4 choose one * 4 choose one, and not 4 choose one. Now what I don’t understand is why do I multiply it by 4 choose one twice and not one][1][1].

[1]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/H03fn.jpg![enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H03fn.jpg!%5Benter) image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpOoj.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

The three of a kind can be any of the 13 ranks. Given a rank, you can make 4 different combinations depending on the suit missing. The other two cards must be any 2 different ranks out of the remaining 12 (otherwise you have a full house) and each card can be any of the 4 suits. So:

$$
N(\text{Three of a kind}) = 13\times 4 \times {12 \choose2} \times 4^2 = 54912 \,.
$$

Comment: Your "other two cards must be 2 of the 12 remaining ranks" condition avoids the possibility of 4 of a kind but it does not obviously avoid a full house.  Do you want one of the remaining 12 ranks followed by one of the remaining 11 (not matching the triple or the 4th card).

Comment: I made an edit to explain it better,  but it was in the formula.

Comment: Yes, I may have read that phrase differently to your intention.